PySpark org.apache.hadoop.fs.UnsupportedFileSystemException: No FileSystem for scheme "null"
When i use spark.read.csv to import a windows local .csv file, this works well. But when i try to read this file in remote windows server, i have the error below:
ps: The path have all the users permissions
24/09/16 15:29:36 WARN FileStreamSink: Assume no metadata directory. Error while looking for metadata directory in the path: //myip/D$/my/path.
org.apache.hadoop.fs.UnsupportedFileSystemException: No FileSystem for scheme "null"
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.getFileSystemClass(FileSystem.java:3443)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.createFileSystem(FileSystem.java:3466)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.access$300(FileSystem.java:174)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.getInternal(FileSystem.java:3574)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.get(FileSystem.java:3521)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(FileSystem.java:540)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path.getFileSystem(Path.java:365)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.FileStreamSink$.hasMetadata(FileStreamSink.scala:53)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.resolveRelation(DataSource.scala:366)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.loadV1Source(DataFrameReader.scala:229)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.$anonfun$load$2(DataFrameReader.scala:211)
        at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:189)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:211)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.csv(DataFrameReader.scala:538)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
        at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:374)
        at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)
        at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
        at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
        at py4j.ClientServerConnection.waitForCommands(ClientServerConnection.java:182)
        at py4j.ClientServerConnection.run(ClientServerConnection.java:106)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750)

I don't know why this happens

does this path exist ?  path: //myip/D$/my/path ?

Yes it's a windows path. Code: df = spark.read.csv(r"//10.X.X.X/D$/my/path", sep=";", header=True). If I change to this other format, works well. Code: df = spark.read.csv(r"D:/my/path", sep=";", header=True)

Spark doesn't support "Windows network paths".

//ip/drive/path is not a valid URI; it has no schema such as hdfs://path, nfs://host:port/path, s3://, file://path, etc.
Spark documents supported filesystems such as NFS, HDFS, S3, local filesystem, etc, but not Windows network paths, i.e. Samba.
